# Loop through text and extract pre-defined words and word pairs in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, text, nlp

I have a large string of text `description`, up to 500 words long. I would like to do the following:

1. Loop through `description` and look for a large number of pre-defined words from array `keywords`, which contains single words, word pairs and word triplets.
2. Every time a match is found, add this match to a new array `matches` (unless already added earlier in the process) and remove the matched word(s) from `description`.

I've had a look around for solutions, but most of them seem to either dive in at the deep end of natural language processing, which would be too complex for my current needs, or simply split the text string on spaces which means that it's then impossible to look for word pairs.

Would greatly appreciate any ideas as to how to do this efficiently.

Comment: seeing as effeiecnt is your main concern, is the 'large number of predefined words' fairly static?  Or is it dynamic?  By 'Efficient'  do you mean 'performant'  or 'effecient' with memory resources?  Or efficient WRT DRY and concise code?

Comment: Yeah, the number of predefined words would be fairly static and probably hover around, say, 300-400. I meant efficient as in DRY and concise code - it's not vital that it's the fastest performing code ever as it will be used in a background process which won't be used very often. Hope this provides some context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
description = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog, and another brown dog"

keywords = ["brown", "lazy", "apple"]

matches = []

keywords.each do |keyword|
  matches << description.match(keyword).to_s if description.match(keyword)
end

puts matches
 #=> ["brown", "lazy"]

matches.each do |keyword|
  description.gsub!(Regexp.new(keyword), '')
end

description.gsub!('  ', ' ')

puts description
 #=> "The quick fox jumped over the dog, and another dog"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Threshold frequency for each word in array

Loop through the text in Description

```
If word matches exactly with description text then increase the threshold frequency by 1 point
```

At the end, words who's frequency grater than 0 put it in to new array matches and delete it from `description`

For Example,

```
If any word repeated for 2 times,
It's frequency will be 0 + 2 and
Initially it should be 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the crude hack that occurred to me :)

```
keywords.select do |keyword| 
  description =~ /\b#{Regexp.escape(keyword)}\b/
  # -or-
  description.gsub(/\b#{Regexp.escape(keyword)}\b/) do |match|
    # whatever
  end
end
```